# /dev/dsp/ и PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio, звукозапись, linux

Что является аналогом старого /dev/dsp или /dev/audio в PulseAudio?
Чтобы я мог считав данные из /dev/dsp получить .wav файл со звуком, который на микрофоне, а послав данные на /dev/dsp услышать этот звук в колонках?

Comment: вы в анабиозе всё это время были ? /dev/dsp это вообще oss, которое тыщу лет не используется, сейчас alsa. 
у PulseAudio есть api программное, нет никакого устройства, чтобы обращаться к PA надо использовать libpulse и никак иначе.

Comment: Искал информацию, на вики никто не уточнил, что это уже не используется

Comment: >> OSS использовался в Linux ядре ветки 2.4. Из‑за наличия закрытого кода и платной лицензии, OSS в Linux в настоящее время заменен на ALSA.

Answer (score 1):

Для программ, использующих только oss, можно использовать padsp.
padsp old_quake